# JDBC sink connector fail with error non-null key non-null struct

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connector, sink

I am new to connector. Doing POC with JDBC sink for oracle. Connector fails with below error
"sink connector is configured with "delete.enabled=true" and pk.mode=record_key" and therefore requires records with non-null key and non-null struct or primitive key schema but found record at topic (**** ) with long key and null key schema .

The data in topic looks like below:
{
"ordertime": *****,
"orderid": **,
"itemid" **,
"address" : {
"city": "abcd view",
"state" : "ab",
"zipcode": 1223,
}
}

Oracle Table  DDL:
create table "schema"."tablename"( "DATA" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE)

Please help me to understand the issue and fix.

removing these both also hit into same error "delete.enabled=true" and pk.mode=record_key"